# How to remove a a substring followed by a dynamic string from a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following string

`search/year/20212022-2/period/value`

And I want to get the results as

`search/period/value` By removing the `year/20212022-2/` from the above string. The `year` is static but `20212022-2` is dynamic.

How could I do this in jQuery?

Comment: Are the values *always* in the given order? If so `split()` the string by `/` and concatenate it back together by the index of the items in the array.

Comment: No. `year/20212022-2` can be in any location inside the string. Just want to remove `year` followed by a `/` and string and then again a `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `year/20212022-2` can be in any location inside the string. Just want to remove year followed by a / and string and then again a /

In this case use a regex to find `/year/` followed by a string of numbers and hyphens to be replaced, like this:

```js
let input = "search/year/20212022-2/period/value";
let output = input.replace(/\/year\/[\d-]+/g, '');

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily with a regular expression:

```js
var str = 'search/year/20212022-2/period/value';

var regex = /(year\/[0-9\-]+\/)/g;

console.log(str.replace(regex, ''));
```

Comment: I believe your solution will only remove numbers after `year`?

Comment: numbers and hyphens. It is the same as the other answer, in fact, just expressed in a different way